# String "array" to real array

Tags: php, arrays

Now I got the string of an array, like this :

```
$str = "array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2)";
```

How can I convert this string into real array ? Is there any "smart way" to do that, other that use explode() ? Because the "string" array could be very complicated some time.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write the string to a file, enclosing the string in a function definition within the file,  and give the file a .php extension.

Then you include the php file in your current module and call the function which will return the array.

Answer (score 12):

Use php's "eval" function.

```
 eval("\$myarray = $str;");
```

Comment: Like others said, beware! Eval will execute everything (imagine mysql queries put by a hacker). Unless you have created the string (and ensured it is "sanitized"), don't use eval.

Answer (score 8):

i don't know a good way to do this (only evil `eval()` wich [realy should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951373/288773)).

but: where do you get that string from? is it something you can affect? if so, using `serialize()` / `unserialize()` would be a much better way.

Answer (score 3):

With a short version of the array `json_decode` works

```php
json_decode('["option", "option2"]')
```

But with the old version just like the OP's asking it doesn't. The only thing it could be done is using [Akash's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266381/string-array-to-real-array/47658246#47658246) or `eval` which I don't really like using.

```php
json_decode('array("option", "option2")')
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to use `eval()`.

A better way to get a textual representation of an array that doesn't need `eval()` to decode is using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) / [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode).

Answer (score 2):

If you can trust the string, use [eval](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). I don't remember the exact syntax, but this should work.

```
$arr = eval($array_string);
```

If the string is given by user input or from another untrusted source, you should **avoid eval() under all circumstances**!

To store Arrays in strings, you should possibly take a look at [serialize](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](http://unserialize).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `eval()` in any case
just call `strtoarray($str, 'keys')` for array with keys and `strtoarray($str)` for array which have no keys.

```
function strtoarray($a, $t = ''){
    $arr = [];
    $a = ltrim($a, '[');
    $a = ltrim($a, 'array(');
    $a = rtrim($a, ']');
    $a = rtrim($a, ')');
    $tmpArr = explode(",", $a);
    foreach ($tmpArr as $v) {
        if($t == 'keys'){
            $tmp = explode("=>", $v);
            $k = $tmp[0]; $nv = $tmp[1];
            $k = trim(trim($k), "'");
            $k = trim(trim($k), '"');
            $nv = trim(trim($nv), "'");
            $nv = trim(trim($nv), '"');
            $arr[$k] = $nv;
        } else {
            $v = trim(trim($v), "'");
            $v = trim(trim($v), '"');
            $arr[] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for sharing this custom function to convert a literal Array from a String 